# submitting form to 2 different websites second via javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have a situation where I want to post form data to 2 diffeent locations at the same time. I do not have control of the locations and they are cross domain.
I found a previous post here, using an iframe, that I can't find now, that I have incorporated. It submits to the first one every time but the second one only gets submitted 25% of the time. I need it to work much more reliably in all the main browsers. Tried using ajax but could not get it to work cross domain in IE trying many solutions posed in this forum.
Thanks.
Ed

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="http://www.firstwebsite.com" onsubmit="return submit2nd()"  >
<input type="email" name="email" value='' />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<script>

function submit2nd(){
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
var uniqueString = "asderwegthyuq123";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.style.display = "none";
iframe.contentWindow.name = uniqueString;
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.target = uniqueString;
form.action = "http://www.secondwebsite.com";
form.method = "POST";
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "hidden";
input.name = "email";
input.value = x;
form.appendChild(input);
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the form upon submission and submit the forms to two iframes with different destinations, or use AJAX. I highly recommend using frameworks such as [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) so you need not worry about compatibility issues.

What's happening to your code is that, it will attempt to submit to the second page during the submission of the first page. If the submission to the first page finishes before its submission to the second, the second submission will not be successful. All scripts in the current page will stop if you leave the page (because you will be going to www.firstwebsite.com).

One solution you can do here is:

1. Change `submit2nd()` so that it will submit for the first and second website.
2. `submit2nd()` should return false so it will not attempt to submit to the page in the `action` attribute.
3. Upon submission (clicking of the submit button), duplicate the form.
4. First form -> change `action` to www.firstwebsite.com -> submit.
5. Second form -> change `action` to www.secondwebsite.com -> submit.

Note: If you wish to use AJAX for this, just make sure that you will not have cross domain issues. In your example, you tried submitting the form to two different domains: firstwebsite.com and secondwebsite.com. You need special settings for this if they are on different domains. You can [read more](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html) about this or check the [explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) of this policy.

Comment: Thanks for the response rationalboss,
Not sure how exactly to implement your solution but I still need to go to www.firstwebsite.com after submission so wouldn't that just create 2 forms that don't reliable submit rather than just one?
Ajax won't work because it needs to work in IE, cross domain, and I can't modify the destinations. I have spent 4 days trying many ajax solutions, none of which work in IE. They work fine in Chrome and FF.

Comment: [JQuery works on Internet Explorer.](http://jquery.com/browser-support/). Upon submission, you can access the parent's location by using `<script type="text/javascript">parent.location.href='http://www.firstwebsite.com/</script>`